# discord bot угадайка

Tags: бот, discord

Недавно увидел бота-угадайку и загорелся идеей сделать его. Но сам я профан и хотел бы научиться, хотя бы посмотреть как работает код. Прошу скинуть шаблон(пожааааалуйста), заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://github.com/cameronleong/guesstheword